# How can I assign integer values to spinner items in strings.xml and read them in my code?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-spinner, android-xml

How can I assign integer values to spinner items in strings.xml and read them in my code?

I have some Items like this:

my displayed string

What I need is to assign an integer value to each item so that in my activities instead of the selected item index I can retrieve that value.

Is there any way to do this in my strings.xml rather than coding in java?
(some thing similar to what we have in HTML)

This is my spinner in layout xml:

> ```
> <Spinner
>     android:id="@+id/tb3SprPriceStartLimit"
>     android:layout_weight="1"
>     android:layout_width="0dp"
>     android:layout_height="40dp"
>     android:entries="@array/priceStartLimitArray" />
> ```

Of course my array is defined in strings.xml
like this:

```
 <string-array name="priceStartLimitArray">
        <item> some text </item>
        <item> some text </item>
```

Comment: By definition, the Strings.xml holds strings. If you need the values as integers, you will have to use the Java code to convert them. Like: int value = Integer.parseInt(string);  You can do this inline when you retrieve the value from the spinner.  So you don't need anything additional.

Comment: My Strings are not numbers. They are text. I need to assign values to them. Not parse or... What I need is I want my spinner (combo box) Items to have values like what we have in HTML.

Comment: oh.  In that case, use:  String valToSet = spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this,

```
<resources>
 <string-array name="app_modes">
    <item tag="101">Beginner</item>
    <item tag="102">Intermediate</item>
    <item tag="103">Expert</item>
 </string-array>
</resources>
```

Now in program you offcourse can get these tag values,

```
int tagValue = Integer.parseInt(modeSpinner.getItemAtPosition(modeSpinner.getSelectedItemPosition()).getTag().toString()));
```

Or by this method,

```
int tagValue = Integer.parseInt(modeSpinner.getSelectedItem().getTag().toString());
```

Hope this will solve your issue,

Comment: It gives the error: getTag() is undefined for the type Object. Casting it to View or Item does not solve the problem.